# I have aproblem with input/output file

Tags: java, file, class, input, output

How i can read this commands from input file ??

```
ADD_CUSTOMER 101 Mohammed Ali Zahrani 555633 ma@kau.edu.sa
ADD_CUSTOMER 102 Sara Ali Ghamdi Maghrabi 502330 sm@kau.edu.sa
ADD_CUSTOMER 103 Hani Ali Shahri 504520 ha@kau.edu.sa
ADD_CUSTOMER 104 Mohammed Faisal Hafeth 514520 mh@kau.edu.sa
ADD_CUSTOMER 105 Hassan Ahmad Sami 502244 as@kau.edu.sa
```

ADD_CUSTOMER –Makes a new customer which is added to the system.  The command will be followed by the following information all on the same line:  cid, an integer representing the ID for Customer;  fName, first name of the customer;  mName, middle name of the customer; lName, last name of the customer; phone number of the customer; email of the customer

i used this import

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;
```

but it cant't found the file!!

thanks for any help

Comment: Try looking into StreamReader. You will be able to read the line one line at a time and then you can use `Split(' ');` on the line to separate out the sections of the Customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code to read customer info from input.txt file

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ReadCustomer {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"))) {
           while (s.hasNextLine()) {
               System.out.println("*******************************");
               String[] tokens = s.nextLine().split(" ");
               System.out.println("cid = " + tokens[1]);
               System.out.println("fName = " + tokens[2]);
               String[] mTokens = Arrays.copyOfRange(tokens, 3, tokens.length - 3);
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               for (String temp : mTokens) {
                   sb.append(temp).append(" ");
               }
               System.out.println("mName = " + sb.toString().trim());
               System.out.println("lName = " + tokens[tokens.length - 3]);
               System.out.println("phone = " + tokens[tokens.length - 2]);
               System.out.println("email = " + tokens[tokens.length - 1]);
               System.out.println("*******************************\n");
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FileReader, here's a tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_filereader_class.htm